# How to convert NSColor to ccColor3B

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone

How would I convert a NSColor to a ccColor3B? The NSColor could be in any colorspace so redComponent etc would not work sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will work, but you can try:

```
    NSColor *color = [NSColor redColor];

    CGFloat red, green, blue;

    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:NULL];

    ccColor3B cccolor = {red / 255.0f, green / 255.0f, blue / 255.0f};
```

Comment: That is not correct, ccColor3B wants GLubyte, but you are giving float. You need ccColor4F or convert float to GLubyte 0-255. Yours would always return {0,0,0}. To make GLubyte you could divide through 255. cccolor = {red/255, green/255, blue/255}

Comment: thats also not good, now you are using double instead of float, thats more than you ever need. I will edit it to float.

Comment: 255.0 is a double literal, that means red / 255.0 will be converted to a double and then back to GLubyte (char). double has double precision to float and when on a 32 bit system uses 2 registers and takes more time to calculate. So use float literal: 255.0f. Edit it yourself if you don't want to accept mine.

Comment: @ViktorLexington oh i see... did i prevent you from editing my answer somehow? sorry if so. I think the most just way will be to publish your own answer for you since you obviously have deeper understanding of the subject than me and i will remove mine then

Comment: Sorry this is not correct all the way. As I said, the colorspace of a NSColor could be any. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -getRed:green:blue:alpha: not valid for the NSColor NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1; need to first convert colorspace.'`

Comment: And you got the conversion wrong. The colors need to be multiplied by 255.0f, not divided. But thanks for trying ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, I found this in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/UsingColorSpaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001807-97360-BCIHDDFF).

```
Can I Access the Components of Any NSColor Object?

It is invalid to use an accessor method related to components of a particular color space on an NSColor object that is not in that color space. For example, NSColor methods such as redComponent and getRed:green:blue:alpha: work on color objects in the calibrated and device RGB color spaces. If you send such a message to an NSColor object in the CMYK color space, an exception is raised.

If you have an NSColor object in an unknown color space and you want to extract its components, you should first convert the color object to a known color space before using the component accessor methods of that color space. For example:

NSColor *aColor = [color colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace];
if (aColor) {
    float rcomp = [aColor redComponent];
}
If the color is already in the requested color space, you get back the original object.
```

Thanks anyway ;-)

So in my case I now use this:

```
NSColor *colorConverted = [self._color colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace];
if (colorConverted) {
    self.labelFormac.color = ccc3(colorConverted.redComponent * 255.0f, colorConverted.greenComponent * 255.0f, colorConverted.blueComponent * 255.0f);
}
```